# How to collect tweets about an event that are posted on specific date using python?

Tags: python, twitter

I wish to collect all tweets containing specific keywords(ex:manchesterattack,manchester) that are posted about the manchester attack from 22may. Can anyone provide me a code to collect tweets using python
I have used following code:

```
import json
import tweepy
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True,  wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="manchester OR manchesterarena OR    manchesterbombing  ", lang="en").items():
    print(json.dumps(tweet._json))
```

I know this code return tweets from last week only. I would like to collect tweets from 22may(more than a week). How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide some example code.

Comment: Please read this: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is `web-scrapping`.

There are a couple of ways to achieve that:

1. [`Twitter API`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public) - simplest
2. Use scrapping tools like `beautifulsoup`, `selenium` etc.

Please do some research about the same. Cheers.